# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in python

Tags: python

I have found many articles related to this post but I no solution provided works in my case.

i have create a file called Thelephony_Test.py and inside, I have:

```
import Preconfig

m_device_cfg = Preconfig.Device_Config(..parameters...)
```

The Preconfig class is defined in the file Preconfig.py as done below

```
import Devices

class Device_Config(Devices):
    def __init___(self, ...parameters...):
        Devices.__init___(...parameters...)
```

The Devices class is defined in Devices.py as below:

```
class Devices(object):
    def __init__(self, ...parameters...):
         self._xxx = parameter1
         self._yyy = parameter2
```

i'm still facing the error below:

```
 File "C:\Users\scayetanot\workspace\AutomationTests\TestScripts\Telephony_Test.py", line 40, in <module>
    m_device_cfg = Preconfig.Device_Config(m_device_adb_id, monkey_mdevice, easymonkey_mdevice, mhierarchyviewer, "M_TEL", mdevicetype)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have tried to change the import of the call from import to from ... import ...

but I still have the issue. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use `Devices.Devices` instead

Comment: or `from Devices import Devices`

Comment: `Preconfig.Preconfig.Device_Config`

Comment: @BadKarma There is no `Preconfig` class in the `Preconfig` module.

Comment: thx iwin it works by using the from .. import in my Preconf file

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
import Devices
```

creates a reference to a *module* called `Devices` in `Preconfig.py`. You can't inherit from a module as you attempt to do in

```
class Device_Config(Devices):
```

You need to inherit from the *class* `Devices` in the module of the same name with

```
class Device_Config(Devices.Devices):
```